# Bug in DateListPlot in Mathematica 10

Tags: plotting, bugs, date-and-time

**Bug introduced in 10.0.0 and fixed in 10.0.1**

---

Mentioned this already in an answer to a related question. `DateListPlot` in *Mathematica* 10 has a horrible bug: If two points have the same time coordinate, only one is plotted; the others are ignored. This is different in *Mathematica* 9, where all points are plotted correctly.

Wolfram tells me that they have this bug in their list to be fixed in the next update. For now I made a workaround with a function that makes identical time coordinates differ by a few seconds, so that `DateListPlot` plots all points. Has anybody another solution?

Comment: This bug is now fixed in the just released version Mathematica 10.0.1

Answer (score 4):

Here's my current workaround. Works only if the distinct time coordinates are sufficiently separated.

```
corr[z_] := 
  Module[{z1, z2},
    z1 = SplitBy[SortBy[z, First], #[[1]] &];
    z2 =
      Table[
        Transpose[{z1[[k, All, 1]] + Range[0, Length[z1[[k]]] - 1], z1[[k, All, 2]]}], 
        {k, Length[z1]}];
    Partition[Flatten[z2], 2]]
```

and `DateListPlot` on a two column array `z` is then called as

```
DateListPlot[corr[z], ...]
```